# How do I deserialize XML namespaces in C# (System.Xml.Serialization)?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, namespaces

I am just putting the finishing touches to my [Zthes format](http://zthes.z3950.org/schema/zthes-1.0.xsd) deserializer (System.Xml.Serialization) which uses the namespace "dc" in the element "thes". All "term" elements are deserializing fine because they have no namespace but I cannot figure out how to tell the deserializer that the "thes" elements have a namespace.

Here is what I am trying to do (which isn't working) so hopefully someone could give me the proper syntax.

```
[XmlElement("namespace:someElement")]
public string SomeElement;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a quick sample for you...

```
[XmlRoot("myObject")]
public class MyObject
{
    [XmlElement("myProp", Namespace = "http://www.whited.us")]
    public string MyProp { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("myOther", Namespace = "http://www.whited.us")]
    public string MyOther { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xnames = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        xnames.Add("w", "http://www.whited.us");
        var xser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var myObj = new MyObject()
            {
                MyProp = "Hello",
                MyOther = "World"
            };
            xser.Serialize(ms, myObj, xnames);
            var res = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            /*
                <?xml version="1.0"?>
                <myObject xmlns:w="http://www.whited.us" w:myOther="World">
                  <w:myProp>Hello</w:myProp>
                </myObject>
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's question is about deserializing, not serializing. The deserialize method does not take a  XmlSerializerNamespaces parameter.

Comment: I guess that is why they accepted my answer 6 years ago,

Answer (score 1):

```
[XmlElement("someElement", Namespace="namespace")]
public string SomeElement;
```

Addendum: Make sure "namespace" is the full URI of the namespace, not just the prefix.