# Why XmlSerializer cannot deserialize xml with schema specified in the root element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-deserialization

I have an xml similar to his one

```
<ns2:person xmlns:ns2="somenamespace">
  <firstName>John</firstName>
  <lastName>John</lastName>
</ns2:person>
```

I try to deserialize it like this:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
b = (Person)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

T is a class

```
[XmlRoot(Name = "person", Namespace = "somenamespace")]
public class Person {
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "firstName")]
    public string fistName {get;set;}
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastName")]
    public string lastName {get;set;}
}
```

after the creation of the object it's properties remain null

the same example works if you remove the schema like `<person>...`

Unfortunately I cannot control the source xml, I need to understand the reason behind and find out a workaround besides altering the xml string (if there is one).

Comment: If you're going to use namespaces in your XML, you need to account for that in your deserialization code. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1545123/1726343.

Comment: Because the `ns` prefix is not defined. This XML is meaningless.

Comment: My mistake there should be ns2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  Namespace = "" to XmlElement attribute

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "person", Namespace = "somenamespace")]
public class Person {
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "firstName", Namespace = "")]
  public string fistName { get; set; }
  [XmlElement(ElementName = "lastName", Namespace = "")]
  public string lastName { get; set; }
}
```